# Tampermonkey - Script not running on Todoist

Tags: tampermonkey, todoist

I want to write a user script for Todoist, but - even though the URL matches - the script is not running on the Todoist but on every other webpage.

Even the simplest example won't run.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Todoist Alert
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @include      https://*todoist.com/app/today*
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=todoist.com
// @grant        GM_log
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    alert("q");
})();
```

Does someone know a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switched to the Plugin Violentmonkey" and it worked. I still don't know what the issue is. But it is solved for me.